# Text File Manipulation Using Python or Unix

Tags: python, file, unix, text

I have a very large text file with data in it but it is not in a form that I need for input into additional tools.  For some reason I just can't get the code right.  The file is too large to open in Excel for modification.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should try to include some code you have tried together with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use pivot table in pandas for that.

Save your excel file as a tab delimited file and read it into pandas

```
import pandas as pd

file_name ="path/to/data.tsv" 
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\t')

df = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index=df["GENE_ID"], columns='Sample_id', aggfunc='first')
```

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GENE_ID': {0: 'GeneA', 1: 'GeneA', 2:'GeneA', 3:'GeneB', 4: 'GeneB', 5: 'GeneB', 6:'GeneC'}, 
                  'Sample_id': {0:'Sample1', 1: 'Sample3', 2: 'Sample2', 3: 'Sample1', 4: 'Sample2', 5:'Sample3', 6:'Sample1'}, 'Value': {0: 10, 1:11, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4:4, 5:3, 6:8} } )
```

df

```
GENE_ID     Sample_id   Value
0   GeneA   Sample1     10
1   GeneA   Sample3     11
2   GeneA   Sample2     5
3   GeneB   Sampl1  4
4   GeneB   Sample2     4
5   GeneB   Sample3     3
6   GeneC   Sample1     8



df.pivot_table(values='Value', index=df["GENE_ID"], columns='Sample_id', aggfunc='first')
```

df

```
Sample_id   Sampl1  Sample1     Sample2     Sample3
GENE_ID                 
GeneA   NaN     10.0    5.0     11.0
GeneB   4.0     NaN     4.0     3.0
GeneC   NaN     8.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Wicked!  Thanks - and apologies as I know I should probably give some code first.  Appreciate it.